# Retrieving Assembly version from AssemblyInfo.cs file with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

Inside the AssemblyInfo.cs file there's this string: `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]` and I am trying to retreive one by one the numbers in it, each one is a variable in the following structure.

```
static struct Version
{
  public static int Major, Minor, Build, Revision;
}
```

I am using this pattern to try to retrieve the numbers:

```
string VersionPattern = @"\[assembly\: AssemblyVersion\(""(\d{1,})\.(\d{1,})\.(\d{1,})\.(\d{1,})""\)\]";
```

However, when I use this code the result is not as expected, instead it shows the full string as if it was the real match and not each number in a Group.

```
Match match = new Regex(VersionPattern).Match(this.mContents);
if (match.Success)
{
  bool success = int.TryParse(match.Groups[0].Value,Version.Major);
  ...
}
```

In this case `this.mContents` is the whole text read from the file and `match.Groups[0].Value` should be "1" from the AssemblyVersion

**My question is to retrieve these numbers one by one with Regex.**

This small tool is to increment the application version everytime Visual Studio builds it and I know there are many tools out there to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first group is showing the full match.  Your version numbers are in groups 1-4:

```
int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, ...)
int.TryParse(match.Groups[2].Value, ...)
int.TryParse(match.Groups[3].Value, ...)
int.TryParse(match.Groups[4].Value, ...)
```

Comment: John Weldon is right. I would recommend using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for testing your regular expressions. It's been a great help to me when I need to test regular expressions once in a blue moon.

Answer (score 3):

The System.Version class will do this for you. Just pass in the version string to the constructor, like so:

```
System.Version(this.mContents);
```

Also, a System.Version can be obtained by the following function calls:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

The build and revision numbers can also automatically be set by specifying a '*' as shown below:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `System.Version(this.mContents);` will throw an exception as the string given does not contains a valid format and `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;`
 is getting the current executing assembly but I wanted to load these version numbers from the AssemblyInfo.cs file

Comment: Yes, your first statement is correct. I also went back and read your initial question and misunderstood. Will `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` work in your case?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on the same problem but I think it will be much easier with a slightly changed pattern.

```
private const string AssemblyVersionStart = @"\[assembly\: AssemblyVersion\(""(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)""\)\]";
```

You get the version by parsing the Groups[1] which will contain something like "1.0.237.2927".

```
try{
    var match= Regex.Match(text, AssemblyVersionStart);
    var version = System.Version.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    ...
}catch(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you must use a regexp instead of:

```
string[] component = this.mContents.Split('.');
bool success = int.TryParse(component[0], out Version.Major);
...
```

Comment: Yes, if the string given is `[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"1.0.0.0\")]` then it will split into `[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"1`, `0`, `0` and `0\")]`